# Comparing lists in python gets weird

Tags: python, list

The following piece of code removes an element of a list and than compares the two lists and should print the element that was removed (item#1)

```py
old = generateList()  #same list
new = old.copy()      #same list

old.remove("item#1")  #remove one of the items

for item in new:
    if item not in old:
        print(item)

#Expecting: "item#1"
#Getting: Nothing
```

The problem is that the lists are big (1700+ items) and the code shown above doesn't work
I tried slicing the list (Made sure the sliced version still had the item (item#1))
With 5 elements the code works.

```py
old = generateList()[0:5]  #same list
new = old.copy()[0:5]      #same list

old.remove("item#1")  #remove one of the items

for item in new:
    if item not in old:
        print(item)

#Expecting: "item#1"
#Getting: "item#1"
```

Anybody knows what's going on here?

Comment: Can you provide an actual data sample instead of some random function `generateList()`?

Comment: Can you add the list values here

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Is there an error? Does it print nothing?

Comment: Do you have duplicate values? `remove` removes the first occurrence only.

Comment: By "doesn't work" I meant that It does not print the missing item.
The example list that raises the problem has 1700+ elements. Is there a way for me to attach it?

Comment: @Guy There are no dupes in the list

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example of `old` or the function `generateList`?

Comment: What is the output of: `sum(1 for x in old if x == "item#1")`?

Comment: @Guyzvi are you sure about the duplicates? it's a big list. `len(set(old))` gives you the same number as `len(old)`?

Comment: @Guyzvi You really should try not to mislead people who are trying to help you. You said "There are no dupes in the list". Twelve minutes later you said "Turns out that the only item I chose to test the code on was a duplicated one". Help us to help you

Comment: @Stuart Yeah you are right, that was an honest mistake because there should be no dupes when dealing with sitemap of a website but I guess there was some kind of a problem along the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess: the item you are removing is duplicated.

`list.remove` removes only the first found item.

Example:

```
old = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A']
new = old.copy()

old.remove('A')
# ['B', 'C', 'A']

'A' in old
# True
```